# e.process is undefined in VueJs application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, environment-variables

So, on my windows machine I defined an environment variable like

```
SET VUE_MAP_PORTAL_TITLE=Map
```

And in my Vue application I try to use it in this way:

```
<v-input hide-details clearable>{{process.env.VUE_MAP_PORTAL_TITLE}}</v-input>
```

However, when I run my application, I get this error message in the console:

> TypeError: "e.process is undefined"

And in debug tools, I see that in fact this construct is undefined: _vm.process

So, what is wrong with that ans how can I fix it. By the way, in .env file this variable is also defined.

Comment: I guess you need to put it into your `data` of component since vue template compiler looks up components props/data/computed rather than global vars.

Comment: @Andrey. I put it inside data like so - `portalTitle: process.env.VUE_MAP_PORTAL_TITLE`. And inside template I use it like `<v-input hide-details clearable>{{portalTitle}}</v-input>`. But it still does not work. However, I'm sure that this environment variable is not empty, since `$ echo %VUE_MAP_PORTAL_TITLE%` returns its value. So, it does not work.

Comment: Well, idk why it doesn't work for you being frank. Maybe smth is wrong with your enve setup. See the [example I've made](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-xe63s)  - it supposed to be working

Comment: It works. variable names must start with `VUE_APP_`